# Exactly what version Composer installs, if there is no version tag given?

Tags: php, composer-php

First scenario. Command executed:

```
composer require "lajax/yii2-language-picker"
```

Results:

- `"lajax/yii2-language-picker": "~1.1"` added to `composer.json` file,
- no local git repository created.

Second scenario. Command executed:

```
composer require 2amigos/yii2-editable-widget
```

Results:

- `"2amigos/yii2-editable-widget": "0.1.*"` added to `composer.json` file,
- no local git repository created.

Third scenario. *I don't remember package name*

Results:

- `"package-name": "dev-master"` added to `composer.json` file,
- local git repository created.

What determines, which version of package will be installed, when requiring a package without specifying version tag?

And what is difference between: `~x.y`, `x.y.*` and `x.y` (no special chars used) in version tag?

Comment: Perhaps the relevant [docs page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions) will help explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the [actual documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions) which answers most of your questions.

Regarding how Composer chooses which version to use when none is specified; It will pick the latest tag release and if that does not exist it will use `dev-master` which is just the latest commit from the master branch.

Comment: Avoid using branches at all cost - it will hurt you in the long run, possibly making your project being unable to update or install any new packages.